# Как изменить слайдер?

Tags: jquery

есть слайдер реализованный в Drupal,слайдеры можно переключать при клике,как сделать чтобы слайды переключались при наведении мышкой?

снизу код и картинка

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    /****
     * запуск слайдер-плагина на 3 окна
     ****/
    $('#slideshow0').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', // transition type
        delay: -300,
        speed: 1000,
        timeout: 5000
    });
    $('#slideshow1').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', // transition type
        delay: 0,
        speed: 1000,
        timeout: 5000
    });
    $('#slideshow2').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', // transition type
        delay: 300,
        speed: 1000,
        timeout: 5000
    });

    /**
     * Запиливание разворачивающихся и сворачивающихся списков
     */
    var $catalogMenu = $('#block-cat-tree');
    if ($catalogMenu.size()) {
        var menuOptions = {
                collapse:   'collapsed',
                expand:     'expanded',
                liActive:   'active-trail',
                act:        'active',
                ul:         'item-cat'
        }

        var menuMethods = {
                setExpanded:    function($li){
                    if ($li.has('ul').size()){
                        $li
                            .addClass(menuOptions.expand)
                            .removeClass(menuOptions.collapse);
                    }
                },
                setExpandedTree:    function($li){
                    this.setExpanded($li);
                    if (!$li.parent().hasClass(menuOptions.ul)){
                        this.setExpandedTree($li.parent().closest('li'));
                    }
                }
        }

        var $liWithUl = $catalogMenu.find('li:has(>ul)').not('.' + menuOptions.expand).not('.' + menuOptions.collapse);

        $liWithUl
            .addClass(menuOptions.collapse)
            .has('ul:visible').removeClass(menuOptions.collapse).addClass(menuOptions.expand);
        var $liActive = $catalogMenu.find('a.' + menuOptions.act).closest('li');
        if ($liActive.size()){
            menuMethods.setExpandedTree($liActive);
        }
        //console.log($liWithUl.size());

        $catalogMenu.find('li.collapsed, li.expanded').find('>span').bind('click', function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();

            var $span = $(this),
                $li = $span.closest('li'),
                $ul = $span.siblings('ul');

            $ul.toggle();
            $li
                .toggleClass(menuOptions.collapse)
                .toggleClass(menuOptions.expand);

        });

    }

    $('.slider').alSlider();

    var $scrollbarX = $('#scrollbarX');
    if ($scrollbarX.size()) {
        $scrollbarX.find('.overview').css('width', ($scrollbarX.find('.overview li').size() * $scrollbarX.find('.overview li:eq(0)').outerWidth(true)) + 'px');
        $scrollbarX.tinyscrollbar({ axis: 'x'});   
    }
});

/**
 * Функция, в которой мы запилим наш слайдер
 */
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({

        alSlider:   function(options){

            var defaults = {
                speed:  500,
                delay:  5000
            };

            var metric = {
                elem:       '.elem',
                title:      '.title',
                text:       '.text',

                // панель управления
                controls:       'controls',
                controlElem:    'page',
                appendix:       'arrow',

                // data-аттрибуты
                dataIndex:      'data-index',

                // активность
                active:         'active'
            };

            options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function(){

                var o = options,
                    slider = $(this);

                // В начале получаем список элементов
                var $elems = slider.find(metric.elem);

                // теперь определим высоту слайдера по первой картинке
                slider.height( parseInt($elems.eq(0).find('img').height()) );

                // Определяем нашу панель управления, которая будет содержать текст из элементов и показывать ее поверх
                // и хвостик, который будет ездить туда-сюда
                var $controls = $('<div class="' + metric.controls + '"></div>'),
                    $appendix = $('<span class="' + metric.appendix + '"></span>');

                $elems.each(function(ind){
                    var text = $('<div class="' + metric.controlElem + '"></div>'),
                        that = $(this);

                    // Проставим им всем атрибут с индексом для связи
                    that.attr(metric.dataIndex, ind);
                    // и для содержимого панели управления тоже
                    text.attr(metric.dataIndex, ind);

                    // ну и активный класс для первой страницы
                    if ( ind == 0 ){
                        text.addClass(metric.active);
                    }

                    that.find(metric.title).clone().appendTo(text);
                    that.find(metric.text).clone().appendTo(text);
                    $controls.append(text);
                });

                $controls.append($appendix);
                slider.after($controls);

                var methods = {
                    slider: slider,
                    sliderElements: $elems,

                    /**
                     * Функция запуска прокрутки картинок
                     */
                    init: function(){
                        var that = this;
                        that.sliderElements.not(':first').hide();
                        that.reApplyInterval();

                        that.controlElems = $controls.find('.' + metric.controlElem);

                        // запиливаем контролеры
                        $controls.delegate('.' + metric.controlElem, 'click', function(){
                            clearInterval(that.timer);

                            var $elem = $(this),
                                pos = $elem.attr(metric.dataIndex);

                            // переставляем активные классы
                            $elem.siblings().removeClass(metric.active).end().addClass(metric.active);

                            that.showImg(pos);
                            that.appendixMove(pos, $controls);
                            that.reApplyInterval();

                        });
                    },

                    /**
                     * Функция перезапускает интервал, если он был сбит
                     */
                    reApplyInterval: function(){
                        var that = this;
                        if(that.timer){
                            clearInterval(that.timer);
                        }
                        that.timer = setInterval(function(){
                            var elemVisible = that.sliderElements.filter(':visible');
                            var elemNext = ( elemVisible.next().size() ) ? elemVisible.next() : that.sliderElements.eq(0);
                            that.showImg();
                        }, o.delay);
                    },

                    /**
                     * Производит смену картинок в слайдере.
                     * Если передан индекс, то меняет на нужную
                     * @param ind {Number} Определяет индекс слайда для показа
                     */
                    showImg: function(ind){
                        var that = this,
                            elemVisible = that.sliderElements.filter(':visible'),
                            elemNext,
                            indMoveTo;
                        if (isNaN(ind)){
                            elemNext = ( elemVisible.next().size() ) ? elemVisible.next() : that.sliderElements.eq(0);
                            indMoveTo = elemNext.attr(metric.dataIndex);
                        }
                        else if (ind != elemVisible.attr(metric.dataIndex) ){
                            elemNext = that.slider.find( metric.elem + ':eq(' + ind + ')' );
                            indMoveTo = ind;
                        }
                        else    {
                            return;
                        }
                        elemVisible.css('z-index','100');
                        elemNext.css('z-index', '99');

                        elemNext.show();
                        elemVisible.fadeOut(o.speed);
                        // перемещаем аппендикс
                        that.appendixMove(indMoveTo);

                        // ну и вешаем активный класс
                        that.controlElems.removeClass(metric.active).eq(indMoveTo).addClass(metric.active);
                    },

                    /**
                     * Функция, которая сдвигает уголок-указатель в панельке управления
                     * @param ind
                     */
                    appendixMove: function(ind){
                        var that = this,
                            $elemMoveTo = that.controlElems.eq(ind);

                        // оцениваем позицию в списке относительно родителя
                        var position = $elemMoveTo.position();

                        // теперь надо найти аппендикс наш
                        if ( !that.appendix ){
                            that.appendix = that.slider.parent().find('.' + metric.appendix);
                        }

                        var newLeftPosition = position.left + Math.floor($elemMoveTo.outerWidth(true) / 2);
                        that.appendix.animate( { left: newLeftPosition + 'px' }, defaults.speed );
                    }
                };

                methods.init();

            });

        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправить

```
// запиливаем контролеры
$controls.delegate('.' + metric.controlElem, 'click'
```

На

```
// запиливаем контролеры
$controls.delegate('.' + metric.controlElem, 'hover'
```

?

Comment: мне нади и так и так,чтобы ghh клике можно менять слайды и наведении тоже менять

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов, вы пробовали скопировать кусок кода "запиливаем контроллеры" и заменить событие click на hover?

Comment: да,все получается.мне надо чтобы и при клике менялись слайды и при наведении
Но при наведении иногда повляется белая картинка вместо обычной картинки,не знаете почему?
А еще можно сделать плавное переключение между слайдами?

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов, соберите рабочий пример на jsFiddle. Без этого я не смогу ответить на вопрос, почему у вас там белая картинка появляется. Плавное переключение сделать можно. На примере, а не вслепую.

Comment: просто сайт сделан на Drupal 7